# IsBlank function not delegable?

Tags: powerapps

[image]

I'm trying to filter out rows on a particular column being blank. It doesn't seem to be delegable. I'm using sharepoint list as a datasource.

Comment: It may be worth to try this: `Time_Out=Blank()`  I have found in some cases that this may be delegated whereas IsBlank() is not.

Comment: @Meneghino you should post that as the answer instead

Comment: @Meneghino, thx so much for the answer, i have another follow up question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424033/filter-user-email-no-delegation
would be great if you can share your expert opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be worth to try this:

`Time_Out=Blank()`

I have found in some cases that this may be delegated whereas IsBlank() is not.

This is not documented anywhere, PowerApps documentation has a long way to go.

Comment: hey this is genius, it seems to work. No more blue dots. is this documented somewhere? Btw, i love your blog big fan

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, sharepoint list does not support IsBlank() as a delegable function. Bummer, might need to switch to SQL server as a data source.

[image]

[Delegable functions and data sources breakdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/delegation-list)

Comment: Azure SQL Database (i.e. SQL Server in the cloud) is much more reliable as a data source in any case.