# Filter User email - no delegation

Tags: powerapps

I'm using powerapps on a sharepoint list datasource. Trying to do a filter based on the current user's email ID on a single line text field in sharepoint. Getting this error,

[image]

I believe there's 2 errors above.

1) User().Email function itself does not support delegation.

2) '=' operator does not support delegation.

---

For (2), not sure why it's giving an error. '=' operator supposed to support delegation,

[image]

For (1), I've saved the User() object into a global variable "CurrentUserG" on start. It seems to fix this error.

[image]

Comment: What is the error shown when you hover over the = sign?

Comment: @Meneghino it says invalid operator

Comment: What type of field is User_Email? Text or person? The former will be easier to deal with

Comment: @Meneghino it's a text field. I switched to this from a Person due to other issues.

Comment: Ok, please see the revised answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you set CurrentUserG=User() at the start and User() returns a record, not a value, then you probably need:

```
Filter(Clock_In_Out, CurrentUserG.Email=User_Email)
```

If you do not get the result you need, remember that text comparisons in PowerApps are case sensitive.  If you have this issue, just use Lower() on both sides of the equation.

Comment: i'm getting an "invalid use of dot operator". Good try though, i almost thought that was the issue too.

Comment: it's still giving me the same error. any ideas? I confirmed that CurrentUserG.Email gives my email address in a text label.

Comment: sure bro will do

Comment: WOW. thanks so much for the skype call. Turns out the issue is with the "User_Email" field. It was changed to "User_Email0". Didn't realise sharepoint list internal names don't change even though the field was.